# Certificate structure for accessing a local device from a web app

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a pretty standard web app (react client, node server), https-enabled.

I want to add the ability for the web app to access a device on the local LAN.  The device has REST APIs and I can install a certificate in it to enable https.

Here's a simplified view of the system:

[image]

I definitely had to put a certificate into the device to make it work in my fully-deployed application, because browsers hate it when you try to do an http fetch in an https-protected app.

Even with the certificate the browser is not happy, I think because it thinks the local server is a different origin.

I've tried enabling cors but not having luck (and here is where i'm at the limit of my knowledge so time to ask for help).

I have been able to get it to work by navigating to the device's web api, which the browser complains about.  If I click on "go to site anyway" (paraphrasing), my API calls work after that.

This is my app I'm hosting, so the solution space can include how I create certs for my server as well as how I configure DNS (I've tried a few things here as well).

So the question(s):

1. Is this even possible within the bounds of a standard web app?
2. If so, what certificate/cors configuration would make this possible.